# How can I enable dark mode on Chrome on Windows 7 so that a webpage being loaded is dark and not white?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

How can I enable dark mode on Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate so that a webpage being loaded is dark and not white?

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`
- [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) Chrome extension

Example:

[image]

Pages are dark otherwise once loaded, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Is your google.com dark? On my PC, all websites, even those which do not support dark mode, change to dark. Try re-installing chrome.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta google.com is dark. Pages are only white sometimes when loading.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I confirmed it by slowing down my network speed. Can you please edit the question and specify that this problem occurs when loading web pages. I know you tried to explain in the 1st line but it is still not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Google Chrome. The developers were notified long ago but no action has been taken. There are very less workaround for this.

1. Change back to light mode and use 3rd party extensions to invert colours. Some are smart enough to not invert images.
2. Use custom builds for chrome that were specifically made for this issue. Keep in mind that those are not updated. [Github Repo Link](https://github.com/hbtlabs/chromium-white-flash-fix)
3. You can open links in new tab without losing focus on current tab. This way, when the new page is loaded completely, you can change the tab without any white flash.
4. Move on to firefox :).
   Good Luck! If you find a better workaround, please notify me.

Comment: Thanks, Firefox has the same issue though https://superuser.com/q/1546226/116475